# Android list view dynamic resizing

Tags: android, listview

I have a list of reviews that I have put into a list, but I would like it to just show a snippet of the text and when the user clicks on the item it resizes and shows the rest of the review.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you want, but the ExpandableListView does something similar.  You can have each Review as a Group and the expanded text/information as the Child.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this more but it seems to be what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

What about: Set the ListItem TextView to some "just 4-5 lines of text" layout height; onItemSelectedListener() would then set the corresponding ListItem TextView layout height to WRAP_CONTENT?

Comment: Thanks, I'd thought of this but thought a more animated thing would look a bit better

Answer (score 0):

The [ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) library may provide something like what you are looking for.
The caveat here is that it essentially just shows 2 views (much like [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)).

So you will need something like:

- **Review Title** (Always Shown)

  - Review Description (Only shown after clicking)